# turn string data into json format

Tags: javascript, php, json

```
note:
 {"category_id":"1","name":"Notes","icon":"images\/note.png"},
quote:
 {"category_id":"2","name":"Quotes","icon":"images\/quote.png"},
project:
 {"category_id":"3","name":"Projects","icon":"images\/project.png"},
skill:
 {"category_id":"4","name":"Skills","icon":"images\/skill.png"}
```

this is what is shown in my console. I have used `json_decode` for my query, and concatenated with string, and I believed that's the caused of the problem.

so how to turn string data into json format?

Comment: I do not understand the problem itself.

Comment: @Tigran assume the block of code is string, convert them into object

Comment: Well, you can not convert to an object. You can create object with parameters, some of them that can be from your string. As I see, you need 4 object where each has (id, name and link to icon), right?

Comment: Have a look here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript

Comment: or get back a JSON to your PHP you must change the content type: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267546/correct-content-type-http-header-for-json , but you must insert this string inside **{}** like: `{ note:{"cat ... skill.png"} }`

Comment: however... why you use `json_decode`... it's trasnform a JSON string into a PHP variable (assoc. array), but for get back it to json for Javascript you may need to use `json_encode()` before.

Answer (score 5):

If that's the string then I'll suggest to wrap it in `{` ... `}` and use `JSON.parse. I.e.:

```
var json = JSON.parse('{' + string + '}');
```

Of course you will need to add JSON lib helper to your page https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Comment: can't it be done in php? I wish not to include extra stuff.

Comment: +1 for **{** add... but i think @user3189052 has other problems before JS string parsing.

Comment: USE: `json_encode()` to a **VALID** json string.

Comment: Yes, you can use `$string = '{'.$string.'}';` and then send the string to the client-side.

Comment: not only... he must add double quotes to properties name (skills, quote,note,project).

Answer (score 0):

you can use `JSON.parse(string)` this will return you a JSON from your string

Comment: have you try to do that before post this answer?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem with PHP not with Javascript:

you have decoded a JSON string for trasform it in a PHP object with `json_decode` work with it... but now you must get back it in a well format JSON string.

But first your string is invalid, for JSON standard (in PHP):

1. Enclose your string in **{**
2. the name of the properties **note, quote, project, skill** must be encapsuled inside `"`
   , your new string:

   {
    "note":{"category_id":"1","name":"Notes","icon":"images/note.png"},
    "quote":{"category_id":"2","name":"Quotes","icon":"images/quote.png"},
    "project"{"category_id":"3","name":"Projects","icon":"images/project.png"},
    "skill":{"category_id":"4","name":"Skills","icon":"images/skill.png"}
   }

and now see this example of JSON encodingi in PHP:

```
$yourString = '{"note":{"category_id":"1","name":"Notes","icon":"images\/note.png"},"quote":{"category_id":"2","name":"Quotes","icon":"images\/quote.png"},"project":{"category_id":"3","name":"Projects","icon":"images\/project.png"},"skill":{"category_id":"4","name":"Skills","icon":"images\/skill.png"}}'; 
$JSON_FOR_PHP = json_decode($yourString);
$JSON_FOR_JS = json_encode($JSON_FOR_PHP);

/* response: */
echo "JSON for PHP (associative Array):<br><br>";
var_dump($JSON_FOR_PHP);
echo"<br><br>";
echo "JSON for JAVASCRIPT (JSON string {add content type: application/json}):<br><br>";
echo $JSON_FOR_JS;
```

response:

```
JSON for PHP (associative Array):

object(stdClass)#1 (4) { ["note"]=> object(stdClass)#2 (3) { ["category_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["name"]=> string(5) "Notes" ["icon"]=> string(15) "images/note.png" } ["quote"]=> object(stdClass)#3 (3) { ["category_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["name"]=> string(6) "Quotes" ["icon"]=> string(16) "images/quote.png" } ["project"]=> object(stdClass)#4 (3) { ["category_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["name"]=> string(8) "Projects" ["icon"]=> string(18) "images/project.png" } ["skill"]=> object(stdClass)#5 (3) { ["category_id"]=> string(1) "4" ["name"]=> string(6) "Skills" ["icon"]=> string(16) "images/skill.png" } }

JSON for JAVASCRIPT (JSON string {add content type: text/json}):

{"note":{"category_id":"1","name":"Notes","icon":"images\/note.png"},"quote":{"category_id":"2","name":"Quotes","icon":"images\/quote.png"},"project":{"category_id":"3","name":"Projects","icon":"images\/project.png"},"skill":{"category_id":"4","name":"Skills","icon":"images\/skill.png"}}
```

if you echo only `$JSON_FOR_JS` and change content type to **application/json** you get the response is a valid JSON string that you can parse with `JSON.parse()` in javascript:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $JSON_FOR_JS;
```

or echo it directly in a JS script (html page or without script tag in .js file):

var js_json = JSON.parse();

now in javascript you have a object js_json with the content of your string.